# Matlab code of median filter or other filters for image enhancement

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am new in matlab and also I don't have much knowledge of digital image processing subject.In this subject,I have chosen the image enhancement topic which is basically used for enhance the image.I have studied some enhancement techniques only theoretical portion so I don't know how to apply filters on image and even I have not found a proper matlab code on the internet of median filters with proper explaination.Please tell me matlab code of median filter or other filters which is easy to understand me .

Comment: http://matlabbyexamples.blogspot.com/2011/12/median-filtering-using-matlab.html

Comment: Also, this question doesn't involve C#, C++, or C. You should only tag your question with tags that are related to that question.

Answer (score 2):

Matlab has a built-in for image median filtering which is [`medfilt2d`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/medfilt2.html).

If you want to design your own filter and play around, you can use [`imfilter`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/imfilter.html) to apply linear filters (i.e. convolve your image with a discrete kernel) and [`nlfilter`](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/images/ref/nlfilter.html) for non linear filters.

**Example:** *(median filter)*

In case you want to apply a median filter on a image `A` using a`NxN` window, you can have your own filtering facility via

```
my_median = @(x) median(x(:))
A_filtered = nlfilter(A,[N N], my_median );
```

To make it more clear, matlab will slide a `NxN` window all over the image "isolating sub-images". 
The function `my_median` (which computes the median on the flattened (i.e. stretched in a row) sub-image) will be applied on each sub-image.

Hence, if you substitute `my_median` with `my_max = @(x) max(x(:))` you will have a max filter and so on.

Comment: I am not allowed to use built-in functions and even I don't understand the code in which u tell about the range.I already told please tell me code of median filter which is easy to understand as soon as possible.Its urgent.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what you need, you first need to define a grid of "relevant pixels" e.g. the first surrounding pixels of the current pixel. Afterwards you calculate the mean or the median of these values and assign it to the current pixel position. Start with a function that finds the neighborhood pixels:

1.) Expand your image in order to have also "neighborhood-pixels" for the borders and define the relevant x,y coordinates from this template (Of course you also need to expand your image with padarray (just look at the function reference) in a symmetric or whatever way to have some information there):

```
  logical_tmp = padarray(logical(ones(xdim,ydim)),[range range]);
  [xc,yc] = meshgrid((1:xdim)+range,(1:ydim)+range);
  indices = int32(sub2ind(size(logical_tmp),yc(:),xc(:)));
```

2.) Define offsets according to the specified range and calculate the indices of the surrounding pixels:

```
  offset1 = [-range:range]; 
  offset2 = offset1.*xdim;
  offs3 = (offset2+offset1);
  pre1 = length(offset1);
  for u=1:length(offset3)
    neighbor_offsets(1+((u-1)*pre1):pre1+((u-1)*pre1)) = offs3(u)+offs1;
  end
  neighbor_offsets = int32(sort(neighbor_offsets,'ascend'));
  neighbors = int32(bsxfun(@plus,indices,neighbor_offsets)); %Indices of neighbours
```

At least that an approach i recently found for myself. Maybe there is a better way to do it. Finally you need to apply the mentioned filter. For example that can be done iteratively (1:size_1d [of your image]) by calculating the mentioned median or mean value row-wise and apply it to the current position.

Comment: thanks for replying and I am not allowed to use built-in functions and even I don't understand the code in which u tell about the range.I already told please tell me code of median filter which is easy to understand .And please this time tell me the matlab code from the starting because I just started studying on this topic and matlab is new for me.Please rply as soon as possible .Its urgent

Answer (score 1):

No built-in functions??? Whats the reason for that? Why are you supposed to use Matlab in that case? Well, but here is how it works the most simplest way "without" built-in functions:

**1.) Main function**

```
function main_function()
  % Read your image
  old_image = imread('yourimage.tif');

  % Loop over each pixel
  for x=1:xdim %loop in x-dimension
    for y=1:ydim % loop in y-dimension
      new_image(x,y) = filter_function(old_image,x,y);
    end
  end
end
```

So whats going on here. At first you read your image with the built-in function imread() into a matrix. If you are not allowed to use that either...well...use it. :P The good thing about programming is, that for a lot of problems very good solutions already exist. Therefore it is highly recommended to use at least a few built-in functions or librarys in every programming language. 
After that there are two loops assigning a new value to each positions (x,y), based on the filter_function and the old_image in the new_image, which at first can be considered basically as an empty matrix.

**2.) Filter Function**

```
function median_value = filter_function(old_image,x,y)
  grid_size = 1;
  neighbors = old_image(x-grid_size:x+grid_size,y-grid_size:y+grid_size);
  %Look for some basic code, that sorts all "neighbor"-values and pick the value in the middle = MEDIAN *
  median_value = from_your_function;
end
```

The filter function calculates iteratively all the new values that should be assigned to the filtered image. So what we have to do here is: **a.)** Find all neighboring pixels, **b.)** Calculate the Median, **c.)** Return it as the return variable of this function.
There is of course now a problem with the line *neighbors = ...*.  What happens at the borders of the image? I already told you about a solution to that, by extending the old_image in all directions. If you want to write your own function for that, you can do that, but favorable is of course the function padarray().  Of course further problems may arise from that solution, like how to define the corresponding position on the expanded matrix to the new_image, that of course should have the same size than the old_image. The solution is also in my first reply. Nevertheless, you can also decide to go on with less information at the border and write some function that reads only "real" pixels.

*Note: This Code will not work unless you solve the problem of the borderpixels.*

Best regards.

Comment: I have a code which is download from somewhere so please check that and tell me whether it is correct or not becoz after run that it give different output not the desired one.

Comment: the code is too long so it is not copy here.what will I do?

Comment: At best you should learn to understand the code. Well, I gave you already all that is needed to write the code you need. I am sorry if you need the code in time, but I do not have time to write this code completely for you, if you are not supposed to use any built-in Matlab function. Thats just stupid (sorry).

Comment: I alrdy said that i am new in this subject and in this coding so I don't know that how the functions is calling in it.I am only use the script editor and facing problem to understand the function calling.

Comment: Well you should definitely do some tutorials first, to understand the basics!